# Odd and even sum

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

There are $n$ distinct balls. In how many ways can they be partitioned into $m$ parts so that first $o$ parts have odd number of balls and second $e$ parts have even number of balls? Here $o+e\le m$. Some parts can get $0$ balls. Order of partition matters: giving $1$ balls to first part and $3$ balls to second part differs from giving $3$ to first part and $1$ to second part.

We could write $$2(x_1+\cdots+x_{o})+o+2(x_{o+1}+\cdots +x_{o+e})+x_{o+e+1}+\cdots+x_m=n$$ and proceed but the balls are distinct so which ball goes in which group matters. How to approach it?

For example if $n=2,m=2,o=2,e=0$ then there are two ways to do this. If the $2$ balls are $x,y$ then partition can be: $(x,y)$ or $(y,x)$.

Comment: With $n=1, m=3, o=2, e=1$, do $0+0+1, 0+1+0, 1+0+0$ count as one or three different ways?

Comment: I've rephrased the problem. Please see if it helps. With those constants there's no valid solution. Since two odd persons require at least $2>1$ balls. If $n=4$ then $3+1+0$ and $1+3+0$ are two different valid solutions.

Comment: Can I ask where the problem comes from?